# How to make td content fill the whole parent?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make content of a table cell fill the whole cell?

I have a simple form organized in a table, labels on the left, inputs on the right and I want the labels to be "full-size" so the user has larger clickable area. Currently he has to click exactly to the label text but the table cell is much larger and it'd be better if the label was expanded.

```
<td>
    <label for="id">Click here will focus the corresponding input</label>
</td>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean the width or the heigh? Or both?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean only the width of the parent `td`, then you can set the `label` to `display:block`:

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="id">Click here will focus the corresponding input</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

td
{
    background:pink;
}
td label
{
    background:yellow;
    display:block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kn5ypr96/

If you need the label to fill the height and the width, then a different approach is required:

```
td
{
    background:pink;
    height:100px;
}
td label
{
    background:yellow;
    display:block;
    height:100%;
}
```

will fill the height and width. https://jsfiddle.net/bL9nvxd0/

Comment: Yes, thank you. Although, this isn't the solution. My <td>s don't have static heights.